# Maximo Spatial: What is the mechanism behind the Set Record Location functionality?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5:

When a user right-clicks on the map,
one of the following messages is displayed: `Set record location` -or- `No actions available`.

[image]

**Question:**

What mechanism does Maximo use to either allow the user to `Set record location` or instead just say `No actions available`?

Is it tucked away in the JavaScript somewhere? Can it be customized/overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-build maximo.ear and deploy it ;-)
But keep in mind that in the future these changed files could be overwritten by a fix or an update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mechanism might be stored in lines 45-67 of `ContextMenu.js`.

- Hint: Search for `"no_actions_available"`
- Where to find the file: `...\webclient\javascript\ibm\tivoli\fwm\mxmap\ContextMenu.js`